# How to make consecutive cells in a table have the same color?

Tags: excel

How do I make cells in Excel that are in one table that have consecutive value have the same shading/background color?

For example:

| Fruits | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Apple | 13/02/2002 |
| Apple | 14/02/2002 |
| Apple | 15/02/2002 |
| Orange | 16/02/2002 |
| Orange | 17/02/2002 |

I need the rows that contain Apples to have one background color and all that contain Oranges to have another. This could be the default shading of Excel tables but the way excel does it is one line at a time.

Note: this list contains 1000s of entries, and the number of repeated row differs, sometimes it is 1 sometimes it is 7 or more.

Thanks!

Comment: I would be looking at Conditional Formatting.

Comment: What did you try?